# Snappy Data Missing Dependencies for Spark class org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, snappydata

I downloaded the snappy data poc from github 
[snappy poc](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappy-poc)

and i am trying to build th project. But it seems there is dependency issue with spark versions. when i build the file using `gradlew generateAdImpressions` I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType
    at io.snappydata.adanalytics.KafkaAdImpressionProducer$.<init>(KafkaAdImpressionProducer.scala:37)
    at io.snappydata.adanalytics.KafkaAdImpressionProducer$.<clinit>(KafkaAdImpressionProducer.scala)
    at io.snappydata.adanalytics.KafkaAdImpressionProducer.main(KafkaAdImpressionProducer.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
:generateAdImpressions FAILED
```

which is because i think the project is using spark_2.11:2.1.1 and this class was removed in version 2.1.0

Here is the gradle file

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.3'
  id 'com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro' version "0.5.0"
}

archivesBaseName = 'snappy-poc'

allprojects {

  version = '1.0.0'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    maven { url "http://repository.snappydata.io/repository/internal" }
    maven { url "http://repository.snappydata.io/repository/snapshots" }
    maven { url "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact" }
    maven { url 'https://clojars.org/repo' }
  }

  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'maven'
  apply plugin: 'scala'
  apply plugin: 'idea'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  apply plugin: "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro"

  ext {
    sparkVersion = '2.1.1'
    snappyVersion = '1.0.0'
  }

  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 4, 'hours'
  }

  dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.6'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.6'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.6'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compileOnly "io.snappydata:snappydata-core_2.11:${snappyVersion}"
  compileOnly "io.snappydata:snappydata-cluster_2.11:${snappyVersion}"
  compileOnly "io.snappydata:snappy-spark-core_2.11:${sparkVersion}"
  compileOnly "io.snappydata:snappy-spark-catalyst_2.11:${sparkVersion}"
  compileOnly "io.snappydata:snappy-spark-sql_2.11:${sparkVersion}"

  // compileOnly "io.snappydata:snappydata-aqp_2.11:${snappyVersion}"

  compile 'com.miguno:kafka-avro-codec_2.10:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT'
  compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.8.2.1'
  compile 'com.twitter:algebird-core_2.10:0.1.11'
  compile 'com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:1.1.5'
  compile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.2'
  compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.3'
}

task generateAvro(type: com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro.GenerateAvroJavaTask) {
  source("src/avro")
  outputDir = file("src/main/java")
}

compileJava.source(generateAvro.outputs)

avro.stringType = "charSequence"


ext {
  assemblyJar = rootProject.tasks.getByPath(':assembly:shadowJar').outputs
}

def assemblyJar = tasks.getByPath(':assembly:shadowJar').outputs

task generateAdImpressions(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
  main = 'io.snappydata.adanalytics.KafkaAdImpressionProducer'
  classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  environment 'PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_JAR', assemblyJar.files.asPath
}

task aggeregateAdImpressions_API(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
  main = 'io.snappydata.adanalytics.SnappyAPILogAggregator'
  jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
  classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  environment 'PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_JAR', assemblyJar.files.asPath
}

task aggeregateAdImpressions_SQL(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
  main = 'io.snappydata.adanalytics.SnappySQLLogAggregator'
  jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
  classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  environment 'PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_JAR', assemblyJar.files.asPath
}

task generateAdImpressions_Socket(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
  main = 'io.snappydata.benchmark.SocketAdImpressionGenerator'
  classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  environment 'PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_JAR', assemblyJar.files.asPath
  maxHeapSize = "8196m"
}

task startSnappyIngestionPerf_Socket(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
  main = 'io.snappydata.benchmark.SocketSnappyIngestionPerf'
  jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
  maxHeapSize = "8196m"
  classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  environment 'PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_JAR', assemblyJar.files.asPath
}

task startSnappyIngestionPerf_CustomReceiver(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
  main = 'io.snappydata.benchmark.CustomReceiverSnappyIngestionPerf'
  jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
  maxHeapSize = "8196m"
  classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  environment 'PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_JAR', assemblyJar.files.asPath
}

task startSnappyIngestionPerf_CSV(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
  main = 'io.snappydata.benchmark.CSVSnappyIngestionPerf'
  jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
  maxHeapSize = "8196m"
  classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  environment 'PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_JAR', assemblyJar.files.asPath
}

task startSnappyIngestionPerf_Kafka(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
  main = 'io.snappydata.benchmark.KafkaSnappyIngestionPerf'
  jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=512m']
  maxHeapSize = "8196m"
  classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  environment 'PROJECT_ASSEMBLY_JAR', assemblyJar.files.asPath
}

task product(type: Exec) {
  dependsOn ':assembly:shadowJar'

  def productDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/snappydata-poc"
  def snappyData = System.env.SNAPPYDATA
  if (snappyData == null || snappyData.length() == 0) {
    snappyData = "${projectDir}/../snappydata"
  }

  doFirst {
    delete productDir
    file("${productDir}/lib").mkdirs()
  }

  // first execute the snappydata "product" target based on env var SNAPPYDATA
  workingDir snappyData
  commandLine './gradlew', 'copyProduct', "-PcopyToDir=${productDir}"

  // lastly copy own assembly fat jar in product lib dir
  doLast {
    copy {
      from assemblyJar
      into "${productDir}/lib"
    }
  }
}
```

Spark 2.1.1 and Spark 2.1.0 have many conflicting dependencies and missing claasses and it is a heck to resolve them. I looked up and it looks like the class DataType was avaialble in 2.1.0.

I am new to gradle, can someone please help me how to selectively add this jar containing old file and still keep 2.1.1 for others.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

snappy-poc uses Spark 2.1.0, which works fine. So you wanted to upgrade it to 2.1.1? I tested quickly with 2.1.1.1 and it works fine for me. Maybe you should try changing spark version to 2.1.1.1 in your build.gradle file